# Method is undefined for the type. Help me fix it

Tags: java, file, methods, boolean

I create private boolean method isMp3() but java say me that this method is undefined for such type.

```
if (directoryItem.isFile() && directoryItem.isMp3()){
    resultListOfFiles.add(directoryItem);
}
```

I don't want to sand to method any values. 
I want use it like boolean method 'isDirectory()'. I know, I do something wrong, show me my mistake, please.

```
private boolean isMp3(){
    Pattern pattern;
    final String FILE_PATTERN = "([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(mp3))$)";
    pattern = Pattern.compile(FILE_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(this.toString());
    if (matcher.find()){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

If I use "this" statement correctly?

Comment: There is probably nothing wrong with `isMp3`. Please include the compilation error and more details as to where the `isMp3` method is defined.

Comment: Where are you calling this method from? Private means you can't use it from other classes, remember... including subclasses.

Comment: Of what type is `directoryItem`?

Comment: DirectoryItem is file, i use this method in Class where method was created. I have no error logs, eclipse warring me.

Comment: @Rudik If it is a `java.io.File`, you can't call `isMp3()` on it (as it is not a member function of `File`). Why don't you pass the `File` object as a parameter to your method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Claus suggested, if you could pass the File object, you can make it work. That's the correct way.

```
public class MyClass {

    public boolean isMp3(File file) {
        Pattern pattern;
        final String FILE_PATTERN = "([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(mp3))$)";
        pattern = Pattern.compile(FILE_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(file.toString());
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        File file = new File("file1.mp3");
        if (isMp3(file)) {
            System.out.println("is an  MP3");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not an MP3");
        }
    }

}
```

In your example, the calling code might look like this,

```
File directoryItem;
// you get 'directoryItem' from somewhere. directoryItem of type 'File'
if (directoryItem.isFile() && isMp3(directoryItem)) {
    resultListOfFiles.add(directoryItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the method as private and it looks like you are not using it inside of the class. If you change the isMp3 method to public this should solve your problem.

See [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for more info.

Comment: If that was the actual issue, then the compiler would say something like 'The method isMp3() from the type Classname is not visible' . When the compiler complains that the method is undefined for that type, that means there is no such method that exists inside the Class.

Comment: My bad. Didn't read the error closely enough and jumped straight into the code.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the compiler error because `directoryItem` is not the same type (class) as the class you have `isMp3` defined (member). Think about whether `isMp3` is defined in a class where is makes sense, and refactor if not since this would indicate poor class design.